# Angular directive variable not getting sent back to rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have a file upload angular directive that works *when not* placed inside of a tabset.
In the code below you will see that after a file is selected, and uploaded, it sets

```
 scope.$parent.file = file;
```

In my controller however, when I try to access $scope.file, it is undefined.  Please see the directive, controller, and template below.  Again, as mentioned, if I place the template *outside* of a tabset (angular ui) then the `upload()` function works - otherwise, I get a "please select a file to upload" error:

fileUpload.js:

```
'use strict';

var fileUploader = angular.module('fileUploader', []);

fileUploader.directive('file', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            file: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){

            el.bind('change', function(event){
                var files = event.target.files;
                var file = files[0];
                scope.file = file;
                scope.$parent.file = file;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

myController:

```
$scope.upload = function() {

            var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: aws.public.bucket } });
            AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: aws.public.access_key,
                                secretAccessKey: aws.public.secret_key });
            AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

            if($scope.file) {
                // Perform File Size Check First
                var fileSize = Math.round(parseInt($scope.file.size));
                if (fileSize > $scope.sizeLimit) {
                    toastr.error('Sorry, your attachment is too big. <br/> Maximum '  + $scope.fileSizeLabel() + ' file attachment allowed','File Too Large');
                    return false;
                }
                // Prepend Unique String To Prevent Overwrites
                var uniqueFileName = $scope.uniqueString() + '-' + $scope.file.name;

                var params = { Key: uniqueFileName, ContentType: $scope.file.type, Body: $scope.file, ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256' };

                bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                    if(err) {
                        toastr.error(err.message,err.code);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Upload Successfully Finished
                        toastr.success('File Uploaded Successfully', 'Done');

                        // Reset The Progress Bar
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $scope.uploadProgress = 0;
                            $scope.$digest();
                        }, 4000);
                    }
                })
                    .on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
                        $scope.uploadProgress = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
                        $scope.$digest();
                    });
            }
            else {
                // No File Selected
                toastr.error('Please select a file to upload');
            }
        }
```

My template:

```
  <div id="videoEditForm" ng-show=" showAddVideoForm || showEditVideoForm">
            <tabset>
                <!-- Videos -->
                <tab id="webVideo">
                    <tab-heading>
                        <i class="fa  fa-film"></i>YouTube Video
                    </tab-heading>
                    <edit-video>video form</edit-video>
                </tab>

                <tab id="uploadVideo">
                    <tab-heading>
                        <i class="fa  fa-film"></i>Upload a Video {{file.name}}
                    </tab-heading>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input class="bottom-marg-15" type="file" name="file" file></input>
                        <!-- Progress Bar -->
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ uploadProgress }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ uploadProgress }}%;">
                                {{ uploadProgress == 0 ? '' : uploadProgress + '%' }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" ng-click="upload()">Upload</a>
                    </div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the above...
turns out I was calling $element.css incorrectly... I was wrapping the css with quotations, but should have been:

```
 link = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.$watch('pos', function () {
                        console.log("position is: "+$scope.pos);
                       $element.css({
                          top: $scope.pos + 'px',
                          position: 'relative'
                        });
                        $attrs.style="top:'+$scope.pos+'px;position:relative;!important'";

                });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

When your directive is added to a tabset, scope.$parent will not point to your controller's scope, but rather to the tab or tabset scope.

A better way to do this is to change your file attribute to a 2-way binding variable in your directive. The directive can then use this variable to set a value that can be used in the controller's scope.

The directive definition:

```
fileUploader.directive('file', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        file: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

        el.bind('change', function(event){
            var files = event.target.files;
            var file = files[0];
            scope.file = file;
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<div file="aFile">
```

aFile will then by a variable in your controller's scope